# what do I need to install to get sql workbench to install

Tags: software-installation, dependencies

I am trying to install sql workbench and Cura Lulzbot Edition but I keep getting the message that it cannot be installed as their are missing dependencies.  Both pkgs are downloaded zip that open into the software installer, both give me the message that the pkg cannot be installed because there are missing dependencies. I have tried installing from bash however I do not know the correct pkg name and nothing I tried worked.

Comment: Exactly what are you doing to install it, and what error messages do you get? [Edit] your question to include this information. As it stands, without any info on how you try to install or an accurate error message, it's difficult to answer.

Comment: You could try installing from Snap